# Что значит "SELECT NULL"?

Tags: mysql

Что значит выражение MySQL `SELECT NULL FROM table_name`?
Как я поняла, оно часто используется в сочетании с `IF EXISTS` или `IF NOT EXISTS`, например:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM table_name WHERE ...)
```

Но для чего оно используется, в чём смысл этого выражения?

Comment: exists все равно какие значения выберет select. с точки зрения оптимизации лучше когда он выбирает не колонку (за которой возможно потребуется лезть на диск лишний раз), а просто какое нибудь произвольное значение. Значение NULL ни чем не хуже любого другого. Лично я обычно пишу select 1 потому как 1 на три символа короче и набирать на клавиатуре быстрее :)

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, теперь всё стало ясно :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В данном случае просто определяется наличие или отсутстствие в таблице `table_name` записи удовлетворяющей условию `WHERE`.
Т.е., если запись (записи) есть, то будет выбрана одна (или несколько) записей с одним полем значением `NULL`, если таких записей нет, то результат будет пустым.

Answer (score 2):

Смысл `select null` - это вывод пустого столбца (ну мало ли, вам надо 13 столбцов выдать, а в таблице только 12 - вот чтобы не изобретать составное поле, на расчет которого сервер потратит время и ресурсы, добавляют в select еще null). В вашем примере это действительно проверка на наличие записей по условию в `WHERE`